# What's the most efficient way to get all emails with a specific type of attachment over IMAP?

Tags: email, imap, attachment

From what I can tell, IMAP SEARCH doesn't support searching by if an email has attachments (except Gmail's variation, which I'm not interested in...I need a general IMAP solution).  Is that correct?

Assuming that's the case, my understanding is that I have to issue a FETCH and filter on the client side.

If this is correct, what's the FETCH that will yield the smallest amount of information that will allow me to filter by attachment type?   I believe it's FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE, but I'd like confirmation.

I looked at FETCH BODY[MIME], but it appears that needs a section number (or numbers) and MIME can't be used by itself. I believe that there can be any number of sections and subsections, and theres no way to specify to search all sections.  Is that correct?

I'm looking for a protocol level answer.  I don't need an answer using any specific language or library.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're right: BODYSTRUCTURE is basically a parsed version of MIME information, which you can then filter on.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm wondering if its the most efficient way.  What I'm concerned about is fetching all emails in an inbox, could be thousands of emails, so I want to reduce the amount of information being sent back to the absolute minimum.

Comment: You can use UID SEARCH HEADER "content-type" "multipart" to get an initial set of UIDs that potentially have attachments, then UID FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE for those to see which ones actually have the type you're looking for.

Comment: I was going to suggest that: you may want to skip ones that have top-level type multipart/alternative.  That's going to be highly server dependant on whether that will actually work though, as extended searches tend to have spotty support.   You could try UID SEARCH HEADER "content-type" "multipart" NOT HEADER "content-type" "multipart/alternative"

Comment: Thanks.  Will that pull in HTML emails though?

Comment: As best as I can tell, gmail always returns empty whenever I try a search "content-type" "multipart"...though no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to get all attachment, you look for their number and names first in imap_fetchstructure->parts, it's an array of file names.
Then to get file content you need to get imap_fetchbody and add 1 to it.
For example, attachment number one is found on section number 2.
I created my Imap solution and it's working well.
based to that you can add you search section